# Bootstrap: space around

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I started with bootstrap and try to create a row with 2 columns. The column right is split up into 2 rows. I try to use "space-around" to get a nicer layout for the column right (vertically), however, it does not work. The two rows are centered instead. Anyone knows why not? btw: the image itself is larger than the 2 rows in the right column.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="container-fluid px-0">

  <div class="row">
    <div class=" col-6">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="pictures/Eriko.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 bg-info">
      <div class="row h-100 align-content-around">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8 text-center bg-danger">
              <h2> Achtergrondinformatie</h2>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis incidunt officia, beatae tempore quis, quam voluptatum fugit error velit voluptates non odio commodi, sunt consequatur hic at molestiae mollitia saepe. Soluta ab doloremque eaque quo, cumque
              exercitationem corporis! Rem sequi modi, provident
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-8 text-center bg-primary">
              <h2> Achtergrondinformatie</h2>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis incidunt officia, beatae tempore quis, quam voluptatum fugit error velit voluptates non odio commodi, sunt consequatur hic at molestiae mollitia saepe. Soluta ab doloremque eaque quo, cumque
              exercitationem corporis! Rem sequi modi, provident
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[screenshot of current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1FpN.png)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the result you are getting?

Comment: I've uploaded an image. Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: What is the result you want to achieve? What does the `space-around` need to do?

Comment: Vertically, I want equal space between the top and row 1, row 1-row 2 and row2 and bottom. So not all stuck in the middle, but spread throughput the column.